# Retrieving document and iframe contents recursively with JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, serialization, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using the following snippet to serialise the contents of a given page:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

However, whenever I try to do that with a page containing an iframe, the contents of the iframe are entirely omitted from the resulting output.

Is there a proper way to layer the contents of iframes where they are supposed to be through JS?

Comment: There's no automatic method and it would be invalid HTML. Also, js can't see the content of cross-origin frames so the solution depends on the environment. For example extensions or WebDriver-based things can access any iframes.

Comment: Would it be possible though through JS to at least build a tree of objects that can have their individual serialised content? The environment would be JS itself.

Comment: Like I said it depends on the environment and the frames themselves. The JS is not an environment strictly speaking, it's just a language. An environment is for example a web page, a node.js script using WebDriver, an extension, etc.